# Limit for choosing button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am designing a website. For my web page, I set buttons as images. we can choose images from the list, but how do set a limit for number of the chosen images. When user tries to go to another page, we can give them an alert if they chose more than 3 images. Here is simple code. I have saw some people use input type to do, but i can add in, because the button will show nothing.
[image]
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button.change").click(function() {
    $("button.change.selected");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  });
  $(".button1.change").click(function() {
    $("button1.change.selected1");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected1");
  });

  $(".button2.change").click(function() {
    $("button1.change.selected2");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected2");
  });

  $(".button3.change").click(function() {
    $("button1.change.selected3");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected3");
  });

});



function descriptionComputer() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ComputerDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description computer";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionCalculus() {
  var x = document.getElementById("CalculusDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description calculus";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionPeridoicl() {
  var x = document.getElementById("PeridoiclDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description peridoicl";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionNone() {
  var x = document.getElementById("NoneDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description None";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}
```

```css
<style>.Button {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(ComputerI.png);
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button1 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(calculusO.png);
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button2 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(periodicO.png);
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button3 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(calculusO.png);
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.selected {
  background: url(ComputerO.png);
}

.selected1 {
  background: url(calculusI.png);
}

.selected2 {
  background: url(periodicI.png);
}

.selected3 {
  background: url(calculusI.png);
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <button onclick="descriptionComputer()" class="button change"></button>
  <div id="ComputerDIV"> </div>

  <br><br>

  <button class="button1 change" onclick="descriptionCalculus()"></button>
  <div id="CalculusDIV"> </div>

  <br><br>
  <button class="button2 change" onclick="descriptionPeridoicl()"></button>
  <div id="PeridoiclDIV"> </div>

  <br><br>
  <button class="button3 change" onclick="descriptionNone()"></button>

  <div id="NoneDIV"> </div>
```

Comment: Why are you including two different versions of jQuery?

Comment: Forget to delete second one. I tried to use other ways to complete, but failed.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do or what the actual issue is. Could you please edit your question to be more clear? Explain what you're trying to do and what the flow should be.

Comment: i have four buttons for users select, i plan let the user only can select 3 of 4. Not all of that.

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this? You're doing everything in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The function to go to the next page can simply count the number of selected boxes:

```
function nextPage() {
    var selectCount = $(".change.selected").length;
    if (selectCount > 3) {
        alert("You've selected too many classes");
    } else {
        window.location = "nextpage.html";
    }
}
```

But you need to use the same `selected` class for all the boxes, not `selected`, `selected1`, etc.

Full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".change").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  });
});



function descriptionComputer() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ComputerDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description computer";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionCalculus() {
  var x = document.getElementById("CalculusDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description calculus";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionPeridoicl() {
  var x = document.getElementById("PeridoiclDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description peridoicl";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionNone() {
  var x = document.getElementById("NoneDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description None";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function nextPage() {
    var selectCount = $(".change.selected").length;
    if (selectCount > 3) {
        alert("You've selected too many classes");
    } else {
        window.location = "nextpage.html";
    }
}
```

```css
.Button {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(ComputerI.png);
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button1 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(calculusO.png);
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button2 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(periodicO.png);
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button3 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(calculusO.png);
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button1.selected {
  background: url(ComputerO.png);
}

.button2.selected {
  background: url(calculusI.png);
}

.button3.selected {
  background: url(periodicI.png);
}

.button4.selected {
  background: url(calculusI.png);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <button onclick="descriptionComputer()" class="button change"></button>
  <div id="ComputerDIV"> </div>

  <br><br>

  <button class="button1 change" onclick="descriptionCalculus()"></button>
  <div id="CalculusDIV"> </div>

  <br><br>
  <button class="button2 change" onclick="descriptionPeridoicl()"></button>
  <div id="PeridoiclDIV"> </div>

  <br><br>
  <button class="button3 change" onclick="descriptionNone()"></button>

  <div id="NoneDIV"> </div>
  <button onclick="nextPage()">Go to next page</button>
```

Comment: Since i add the code in, when i click the next page button. It didn't check how many images that i select, just go next page.

Comment: I didn't notice that you were toggling different `selected`, `selected1`, etc. classes. You should use the same class for all of them so you can count them properly. I've updated the answer.